# LG Ultrafine 5k display with Dell XPS 13 not displaying 5K

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, display-resolution, wayland, lg

So my employer gave me an LG Ultrafine 5k display to use and I am having a weird issue.

First of all, my laptop detects the one display as two displays: one that has a max resolution of 4096x2304 and the other that only has one possible resolution: 5k. The second display is not actually visible and if you put windows into it, they disappear. The 4K display works 100% perfectly and did so out of the box.

This is a pretty minor complaint and I am not really concerned if 5k is not possible (4K is fine for my use case) but it would be cool if I could push it to 5k. It is probably a Wayland issue (as pretty much every issue I have had since installing the new Ubuntu is...)

System Information:

- Dell XPS 13 9360 (Not developer edition)
- Ubuntu 17.10 (using Wayland)
- LG Ultrafine 5k Display

Xrandr Output with all monitors enabled:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 9856 x 2880, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm
   3200x1800     59.96*+
XWAYLAND2 connected 4096x2304+3200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   4096x2304     59.99*+
XWAYLAND3 connected 2560x2880+7296+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   2560x2880     59.96*+
```

Answer (score 1):

The monitor is made up of two panels, each connected by its own display port (because of the bandwidth limitation). To get 5k, you have to connect both display ports and set each display to 2560x2880.